# Animating Two Objects' Interaction?

Tags: animation, skeletal-animation

I want to animate a character who could be doing any number of things.

Say for example, I want the character to get into bed, under the covers. Do I animate the character and the sheets moving together? Separately? If separately do I need to call both animations simultaneously to ensure it fits together properly?

Or, if two characters are going to hug. Do I animate them hugging or just animate them separately hugging and try to align them in-game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You animate them separately, as if they were together, and position them together in game. For 2D, you can use something like spine, which lets you animate all the parts of a character. Then, for the hugging example, you just animate a character hugging the air, and in game ensure that the character is positioned properly.

At least this one way you could do it. I'm sure there are others, like per rendered cutscenes. (That isn't suitable for basic interactions though!)

Let me provide you with some examples.
A player throws a ball; because the ball needs to be detached, you animate the character and bind the ball to the hand, until the frame where the ball is released. You then apply physics to the ball.

A player gets out of bed; this is tricky because I don't know what you want this to look like. In an advanced 3D game you might want to simulate it, but in a little 2d game you could just have the player being animated to get up.

Hope this has helped.